# Turning jpg photos into Coloring Sheets

Tags: ubuntu, drawing

Is there an Open Source program that will run on Ubuntu, that I could use to simply make coloring sheets from my jpg pictures?

Answer (score 1):

Install inkscape:

```
sudo apt-get install inkscape
```

then load the jpeg image. Click on the Paths menu item, then on Trace Bitmap. There's a tutorial [here](http://inkscape.org/doc/tracing/tutorial-tracing.html).

Answer (score 1):

Gimp?

Original:

[image]

Posterised (6 levels) and oilified:

[image]

Edge detect:

[image]

---

Also see an [ImageMagick example](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/photos/#color-in).

Comment: This looks good - I will try and find a tutorial on this aspect of Gimp and give it a try. If there happens to surface another idea or program that is simpler for a novice, I would certainly appreciate hearing about it also. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Repeatedly running median filter with medium-sized area and then making it indexed image with just n colors also works.